# Dragdrop of image in grid

Tags: c#, wpf

There is a grid which has 4 rows and 4 cols,   there is an image im at(0,0). Now I want to dragdrop this image into other cell of the gird. Please see the following code

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Grid g = new Grid();
            g.Height = 200;
            g.Width = 200;
            g.AllowDrop = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                RowDefinition row1 = new RowDefinition();
                row1.Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
                g.RowDefinitions.Add(row1);
            }


            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                ColumnDefinition col1 = new ColumnDefinition();
                col1.Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
                g.ColumnDefinitions.Add(col1);
            }
            g.ShowGridLines = true;
            this.Content = g;

            **g.DragEnter +=new DragEventHandler(g_DragEnter);
            g.DragLeave +=new DragEventHandler(g_DragLeave);**

            Image im = new Image();
            Uri ur = new Uri("im.bmp");

            BitmapImage b = new BitmapImage(ur);

            im.Source = b;
            g.Children.Add(im);
        }

        public void g_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public void g_DragLeave(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {

        }


    }
```

I have added two event: DragEnter and DragLeave to the grid. But theses events are not getting fired and this code is not working correctly.

Please help me in writing appropriate events explaining how the image will be dragged from one cell to other cell

Answer (score 0):

I think in WPF you have to do a little bit more programming, look at this site: http://www.wpftutorial.net/DragAndDrop.html